# Update data in database in some time period

Tags: multithreading, stored-procedures, lazarus, freepascal

I have a problem with updating some data in my DB each time, i.e each minute.
So I am using Lazarus as programming language and created linux daemon app, application contain one thread in which I have all logic which is involved in getting data from database

```
uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils, daemonapp, Unit1, math;
....
TProcThread = class(TThread)
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdVars;
    procedure UpdLogs;
  end;

TDaemon = class(TCustomDaemon)
  private
         FThread: TProcThread;
         procedure ThreadStopped (Sender: TObject);
  public
         function Start: Boolean; override;
         function Stop: Boolean; override;
         function Execute: Boolean; override;
         function Install: Boolean; override;
         function UnInstall: Boolean; override;
  end;

procedure TProcThread.UpdVars;
begin
// update database
end;

procedure TProcThread.UpdLogs;
begin
// update database
end;

procedure TProcThread.Execute;
begin
repeat
while not (Query.EOF) do begin
//////
//doing stufff
//////
sleep(1000);
UpdVars;
end;
sleep(60000); // <= if I put this sleep than UpdVars don't update every second, but it updates 1sec + 60000 seconds
UpdLogs;
until Terminated;
end;

constructor TJPDaemonMapper.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
        d: TDaemonDef;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  d:= DaemonDefs.Add as TDaemonDef;
  d.DisplayName:= 'MyService';
  d.Name:= 'myservice';
  d.DaemonClassName:= 'TDaemon';
  d.WinBindings.ServiceType:= stWin32;
end;


{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Title:='MyService';
  RegisterDaemonClass(TDaemon);
  RegisterDaemonMapper(TJPDaemonMapper);
  DataModule1:= TDataModule1.Create(nil);

  Application.Run;
end.
```

And I want to update my log table every minute, also I have one procedure `UpdVars` which also need to be executed every second, this one I have got by put `sleep(1000)` after executing this procedure in main `while` loop which is getting data from database. But if I put second sleep before log update procedure, I don't get needed update frequency in `UpdVars` procedure...
So I am stuck on this thing, **how to execute procedure in specific time** for each procedure it is different... can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a TTimer and a state machine. In every timer event, check if something needs to be done, and if so, advance the state machine.

A low res timer routine can also feed a scheduler. Jedi JCL has an example, but IMHO it is a bit unwieldy.